# Java Program Error in MSDOS Window: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program in Java that will take an input from the user and convert to Celsius or Fahrenheit. So the user will input some number, a space, then a C or F. Thee program compiles fine but when I try to test it I get the following messages:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: (whatever number, space, F/C I put in to test it0

    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt<Integer.java:492>
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt<Integer.java:527>
    at Temp.Conv.main<TempConv.java:14>
```

I'm guessing that Java doesn't like me trying to search for integers in a string using Parse.
Any suggestions for how else to accomplish it?

Here is the code: (Just so you know, I know the brackets and spaces are off but this site won't allow me to fix it)

```
public class TempConv
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String reply = "y";
  while( reply.equalsIgnoreCase("y") )
    {
        System.out.println("Enter temp (ex. 70 F or 23 C): ");
        String CF = input.nextLine(); // inputs string
        int temp = Integer.parseInt(CF); // to get integers from string
        for (int i = 0; i < CF.length(); ++i)
        {
            char aChar = CF.charAt(i);
            if (aChar == 'F') // looking in string for F
            // go to f2c()
            {
                f2c(temp);
            }
            else if (aChar == 'C') // looking for C
            // go to c2f()
            {
                c2f(temp);
            }
        }
    System.out.println("Would you like to covert another temp? <y/n> ");
    reply = input.next();
    }
}
static void f2c(int j)
{
    int c = (j - 32)*(5/9);
    System.out.println(j + "F = " + c + "C");
}

static void c2f(int k)
{
    int f = (k*(5/9))+32;
    System.out.println(k + "C = " + f + "F");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Integer.parseInt` will try to parse the entire string that you pass. If you pass e.g. `"75F"` then the method will fail with the exception that you see.

You'll need to do your own input validation. If you expect a certain format from the user, you'll need to check that the input matches the format, then extract the part of the input that matches the number, and pass it to `Integer.parseInt`: check the last character for `C` or `F`, and pass the substring that precedes that character to `Integer.parseInt`. Wrap the call in a `try/catch` block so that you can continue to ask/loop if the input is still malformed.

You can use `Scanner.nextInt` to grab numbers from the input, but if your inputs look like `75F`, then `Scanner.nextInt` will fail with an `InputMismatchException`.

Answer (score 0):

```
String CF = input.nextLine(); // inputs string
int temp = Integer.parseInt(CF); //
```

is problematic. How do you know that an user always enters integer values ? Here it is trying to parse for eg 10C or 10 F which is not a valid integer. When you are `nextLine` method it returns any string and  it is not necessary that it should be a number. Handle that in a try catch ,

```
try {
temp  = Integer.parseInt(CF);
} catch () {
 //handle
}
```

but before even doing this you must split the C or F away from the original string to do integer parsing.